# Как исключить не цифры при помощи do while?

Tags: javascript, циклы, prompt

В общем есть тз если пользователь ввёл не правильную дату рождения то зациклить prompt() до того момента пока не введёт правильно . Минимальный и максимальный год как бы поставил и работает .
Сейчас стоит задача зациклить если пользователь укажет не цифры или нажмет отмена .

```js
const CURRENT_YEAR = 2022;

let birthYear = null;

const MIN_BIRTH_YEAR = 1900;
const MAX_BIRTH_YEAR = CURRENT_YEAR;


do {
  const input = Number(
    prompt(`Укажите ваш год рождения : только целые числа, min ${MIN_BIRTH_YEAR}, max ${MAX_BIRTH_YEAR}`, 1995)
  );

  birthYear = input;
} while (birthYear < MIN_BIRTH_YEAR || birthYear > MAX_BIRTH_YEAR);

console.log(birthYear);
```

Думал можно так но увы :

```js
while (birthYear < MIN_BIRTH_YEAR || birthYear > MAX_BIRTH_YEAR || birthYear != Number);
```

Comment: `typeof birthYear !== 'number'` ?

Comment: лучше использовать встроенный в `html` специфичный тэг `input` с возможность вводить только цифр `<input type="number">` , и прямо во время ввода (когда `focus` === true по событию `change` (можно добавить события `input`, `paste` и `keyup` для покрытия всех случаев) проверять `value` по вашим условиям, меняя надпись (год ок или не ок) рядом/под вводом.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
do {
  const input = Number(
    prompt(`Укажите ваш год рождения : только целые числа, min ${MIN_BIRTH_YEAR}, max ${MAX_BIRTH_YEAR}`, 1995)
  );

  birthYear = input;
} while (birthYear < MIN_BIRTH_YEAR || birthYear > MAX_BIRTH_YEAR || isNaN(birthYear));
```